# woocommerce single product page hook not working

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, woocommerce-offtopic

I have written a function which will display a date picker and a select box. I want this function output to be displayed on woocommerce single product page. So I assigned my function to a hook woocommerce_after_single_product_summary and I am not seeing any fields appearing in the product page. Can anyone please help?.

so far per my knowledge the function is working fine as I have tested it using its shortcode in a page. Below is the hook I am trying to add, timeslot_display is my function also I have added a screenshot of my function output.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'timeslot_display')
```

[image]

Comment: can you please include your timeslot_display() function definition?

Comment: Here I am building a woocommerce based plugin where the product authors (I have assigned authors to product posts) load their timeslots in user meta. timeslot_display() returns the date and timeslot fields based in user meta according to product author. The output of timeslot_display() is to be displayed on product page.

Comment: Have you passing any parameter to timslot_display() function?

Comment: no, I am getting the values within the function like user Id from get_current_user_id() kind of functions....based on the current logged in user and posts by the current user.

Comment: which theme are you using?

Comment: on 1st line of timeslot_display(), just echo something and do exit(). Just for checking your function is called or not.

Comment: I just did it but nothing happened, may be the function if not called properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26788/discussion-between-wisdmlabs-and-krishna89).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks WisdmLabs. I traced it finally after the discussion. The changes in product page are appearing now. Below is the mistake I have done.I am posting this as it might help others with similar problems.
In my plugin I am calling file B in file A using require_once. I have placed my function timeslot_display() and hook calling line in file B which did not give any results. When I copied the entire code of file B to file A, then I am able to see the changes in product page. Not sure why this happened but it worked.